# Manifold varieties admitting a polynomial parametrization

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Let polynomials $p_1,\dots,p_K\in {\mathbb{C}}[Z_1,\dots, Z_N]$ define the variety $V(p_1,\dots,p_K)=\{ {\mathbf{z}} \in {\mathbb{C}}^N: p_k(\mathbf{z})=0 \;\forall \; 1\leq k\leq K \},$ so that $V(p_1,\dots, p_K)$ also happens to be a manifold of dimension $n$ ($ < N$).

Is there some natural algebraic description of the polynomials $p_1,\dots, p_n$ so that there exists a polynomial parametrization of the variety $V(p_1,\dots,p_n)$, that is, there exist polynomials $Z_1,\dots, Z_N\in \mathbb{C}[X_1,\dots, X_n]$ such that $V(p_1,\dots,p_K)=\{(Z_1(\mathbf{x}),\dots, Z_N(\mathbf{x})): \mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{C}^n\}$?

Comment: Unirationality is a weaker property than this, and I think there is no straightforward test for unirationality, so probably not.

Comment: Thanks, I now understand that this is a much well known problem in the algebraic geometry world, which I am ignorant of.